# AOP pointcut is only working for methods which are annotated

Tags: java, spring-boot, aop, spring-aop, spring-annotations

I am using the AspectJ and Spring AOP, but I am facing a weird problem the pointcut is working for only those methods which has some annotaiton above them e.g, ovverride,Bean and etc. The point cut is not working for local methods of the class which are not annotated.

below is the config I am using:

```
@Aspect
@Configuration
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy(proxyTargetClass = true)
//@EnableLoadTimeWeaving
public class AspectLogging {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(AspectLogging.class);




      @Pointcut("execution(public * *(..))")//Public 
      public void publicMethod(){};

      @Pointcut("execution(protected * *(..))")//Protected 
      public void protectedMethod(){}

      //@Pointcut("execution(* com.s4m.user.*.*(..))")
      @Pointcut("within(com.s4m.user..*)")
     // @Pointcut("@annotation(Service)")
      public void annotationPointcut(){}

      @Pointcut("execution(private * *(..))")//Protected 

      public void privateMethod(){}


    @Before("annotationPointcut() && (protectedMethod() || publicMethod()  || privateMethod())")
    public void test(JoinPoint joinpoint) {
          logger.info(joinpoint.getSourceLocation().getWithinType().getSimpleName() +" :: "+ joinpoint.getSignature().getName() + " **Entry**");
    }

}
```

For example below are the methods of the same class, the pointcut is working for annotated method but not for the other method.

```
@Override
    public Object logout(HttpServletRequest request) {
        loggingOut(request);
        return Utility.getResponseModel(ApiConstants.SUCCESS);
    }

    public void loggingOut(HttpServletRequest request) {
        HttpSession session = request.getSession();
        RedisUser redis = redisUserRepository.findById(request.getHeader(ApiConstants.DEVICE_ID));
        if (!Util.objectIsNull(redis)) {
            deleteUserInRedis(redis);
            saveAuditTrail(ApiConstants.LOGOUT, redis.getSessionId(), redis.getName(), redis.getDeviceId(),
                    ApiConstants.OPERATION_SUCCESSFUL, true);
        }
        session.invalidate();
    }
```

logs for above method:

```
AC66A549C3416D3 2019-10-02 15:51:08 [http-nio-8302-exec-2] INFO  com.s4m.user.config.AspectLogging -CITI-P_003(AD PLUGIN)- UserServiceImpl :: logout**Entry**
```

but there are no logs for this method, because pointcut is not working:

```
public void loggingOutTest() {

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Spring AOP is working only for Spring beans (Spring beans could be created also by annotating the class). And also you can intercept only public methods call. Only limited functionality of AspectJ is supported here.

P.S. JPA entities also couldn't be used by Spring AOP.

Comment: so how can I make the point cut work for normal methods? which doesn't have any annotations ?

Comment: Don't think I can help you much here. I guess you should use some extra libraries to make a full support for AspectJ in Spring. May be these links could help https://www.baeldung.com/aspectj
https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html  

Also you can use classic JavaEE stack which support AspectJ out of box.

Answer (score 0):

Spring AOP could only recognize Spring beans. if you want to use other object like JPA entities try to add AspectJ dependency : 
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.aspectj/aspectjrt

Comment: okay I have added the other dependecy and I am not using the Spring AOP any more only the AspectJ, do I need to change any config above? Because it's still not working after adding the aspectj dependency.